# CSS properties aren't updated

Tags: jquery, css

i had a code with the .toggle() method which worked fine but had to replace the .toggle() with .on('click'..) to be able to unbind it with the .off() method later.

Here is the first code with the toggle() method :

```
        var befrestorex;
        var befrestorey;
        var befrestorew;
        var befrestoreh;
        var toggled =false;

    $('#restorebtndiv').toggle(
        function(){

        befrestorex = $('#windowdiv').css('left');
        befrestorey = $('#windowdiv').css('top');
        befrestorew = $('#windowdiv').css('width');
        befrestoreh = $('#windowdiv').css('height');


        windowScrollTopBrestore = $(document).scrollTop()+'px';
        console.log(windowScrollTopBrestore);

     $('#windowdiv').css({'left':'0px','top':windowScrollTopBrestore,'width':'100%','bottom':'50px','height':'100%'});  


        },function(){           

            $('#windowdiv').css({'left':befrestorex,'top':befrestorey,'width':befrestorew,'height':befrestoreh});

});
```

The second code is :

```
var befrestorex;
var befrestorey;
var befrestorew;
var befrestoreh;
var toggled =false;

$('#restorebtndiv').on('click', function(){


    console.log("function started ...");
    befrestorex = $('#windowdiv').css('left');
    befrestorey = $('#windowdiv').css('top');
    befrestorew = $('#windowdiv').css('width');
    befrestoreh = $('#windowdiv').css('height');


    if (!toggled){

           toggled=true;

        windowScrollTopBrestore = $(document).scrollTop()+'px';
        console.log(windowScrollTopBrestore);


        $('#windowdiv').css({'left':'0px','top': windowScrollTopBrestore,'width':'100%','bottom':'50px','height':'100%'});


    }
    else {          
           toggled=false;

           $('#windowdiv').css({'left':befrestorex,'top':befrestorey,'width':befrestorew,'height':befrestoreh});
           console.log(toggled);
    }
});
```

and here in the "else" , the $('#windowdiv').css({'left':befrestorex,'top':befrestorey,'width':befrestorew,'height':befrestoreh});
has no effect on the matched div.it s weird becose in the first code it was working without any problem. i googled to find a way to refresh the div with jquery , i found the solution to use .fadeIn('fast') but it didn't neither work.
Someone have an idea ?

Comment: can't u use the toggle one and unbind with .unbind()?

Comment: i think no , toggle isn't an event.

Comment: yes you can http://jsfiddle.net/DfEXR/

Comment: The problem is that unbind isn't specific and it will unbind all events and what i want is only to unbind the "toggle" which isn't an event, so that isn't the best solution.